# Why Android Studio Dolphin can't open in Mac

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated my Android Studio from old version to the latest one

but somehow it can't open after update

Very weird and there is no response at all (see screen recording

I also try uninstall and reinstall but not working

How to solve it? Any help will be appreciated.

My macOs

[image]

[screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg1uP.jpg)

Comment: Try starting it from the command line and see what errors (if any) get reported in the Terminal window.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank for comments. I have tried, but the result is the same, there is no response at all

Comment: @GHH Did you resolve this? Having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the latest canary version `Android Studio Flamingo (2022.2.1) Canary 8 November 7, 2022` from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive and now it is working well.

Answer (score -3):

That's because you are intel version and you didn't install the intel version of android studio on MacOS , i had this issue fixed by installing the 1st version

Comment: For my case I dowload the mac chip version

Comment: I have also download mac version but its not working.